# Compound query with union-all and order-by sorts only the last part instead of the whole query

Tags: oracle, insert, sql-order-by

This works as expected:

```
select * from table(sys.OdciNumberList(2,1,3))
union all
select * from table(sys.OdciNumberList(5,6,4))
union all
select * from table(sys.OdciNumberList(9,7,8))
order by 1;
```

And this works as expected:

```
create table q1(id number generated always as identity, val number);

insert into q1 (val)
select * from table(sys.OdciNumberList(2,1,3))
order by 1;

select * from q1 order by id;
```

But not this one:

```
create table q3(id number generated always as identity, val number);

insert into q3 (val)
select * from table(sys.OdciNumberList(2,1,3))
union all
select * from table(sys.OdciNumberList(5,6,4))
union all
select * from table(sys.OdciNumberList(9,7,8))
order by 1;

select * from q3 order by id;
```

I received the following result: `2 1 3  5 6 4  7 8 9` - that is, only the last three numbers are sorted.
My question is:  **Why does it behave this way?**

P.S.  I know I can workaround this by wrapping the compound query with `select * from (...)`.

Comment: Relational data isn't supposed to have the concept of row order. When you insert data into a table, the order the rows go in in a single SQL statement should be irrelevant. Ordering is for pulling data out, not for putting it in. I think Oracle feels in this situation at liberty to use a cheaper plan that avoids or limits the size of this unnecessary sort by applying it only to the last set. It's more a question of why it bothers with even that.

Comment: @PaulW It is not certainly in that way. Row order may have meaning on insert. For example, to reduce clustering factor of index. See https://dbfiddle.uk/BVWKJyK5

Comment: @astentx, that's a performance concern that takes advantage of how storage works to decrease block reads, not part of relational theory that is about meaning. There are certainly some reasons for ordering inserts, like compression efficiency, etc... but most programmer's shouldn't be thinking of ordering data on its way into a table. It encourages non-relational thinking.

Comment: @PaulW - you are wrong.  Row ordering on insert is a fairly common technique, and Oracle does guarantee the order will be preserved for some circumstances. So row order on insert does matter. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14962856/20468470)

Comment: @ESkri, you're not reading my comments carefully. Ordering inserts is of course a common technique for increasing compression efficiency and reducing clustering factor of an index, but those are internal mechanics that have performance considerations only. Why do you suppose that old documentation you linked to explicitly says the order is not guaranteed across extent boundaries? Where there is no guarantee, it cannot be relied on to convey meaning. They are not logical in nature. Relational rows have no concept of order at rest in a database unless such a concept is imposed on them with data.

Comment: The only *logical* reason why OP would want the rows ordered is to get the identity column value to correlate with one of the data columns. But an identity column is just a sequence under the covers, which is designed to guarantee uniqueness, not order. As long as they assign a unique value to each row, they have done their job regardless of what row was assigned what value. Trying to force them to assign numbers in a given order is not what they were intended for. This is a symptom of thinking non-relationally. I don't think Oracle should feel obliged to *guarantee* any order on insert.

Comment: @PaulW - `but those are internal mechanics that have performance considerations only` - So, why I should not care about performance? `Relational rows have no concept of order` - My SO question is practical, and it is about Oracle, it's not about pure relational concepts, so you are off-topic here.

Comment: `Trying to force them to assign numbers in a given order is not what they were intended for` - I used identity column here just to illustrate the sequence of inserting rows. Can the order of inserting rows be different from the order of identity column?  I'm assuming they are the same.

Comment: @ESkri, yes they can, particularly with multiple sessions doing this concurrently and caching values privately and inserting at different speeds, which is even more pronounced across instances in a RAC database. And that's just the sequence/identity value... if you also are thinking of physical row location in blocks wtihin extents, it's all over the place, as Oracle fills free space in whatever blocks have them, crosses extents (even datafiles), migrates rows, etc... all of which gets changed all over again on a move operation. Oracle isn't going to make promises about physical ordering.

Answer (score -1):

Whilst there will likely be some ordering when you do a INSERT-SELECT-ORDER-BY into an empty table, simply due to the population of blocks, there really are no guarantees (as others have pointed out).

If you really want to have some control over where the data is being place, then you'll need to look at options such as attribute clustering, which still are applied during direct-mode operations (insert-append, CTAS, alter table move etc).

A walkthrough of that feature is here

https://youtu.be/UndmvLZ4KSI

Alternatively for non-direct load operations you could then look at options that pre-determine the physical storage of the data such as

- index organised tables
- b-tree clusters
- hash clusters

Comment: This does not answer the question in my post.

Comment: Downvote because of the phrase `there really are no guarantees`.  Oracle does guarantee the sequence of rows inside a single data block (excluding old rows existing in this block).